# as3 find last occur of a specific string

Tags: actionscript-3

Quick question, ***indexof()*** find the first occur position of the string character? what about last occur of the string character?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite literally:

[`.lastIndexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#lastIndexOf%28%29)